# Faster way to find the first four non-zero terms of the Maclaurin series for $\frac{1-x}{1+x}\cosh\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

I want to find the first 4 non-zero terms for :

$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}\cosh\sqrt{x}$$
Before expanding, I rewrite this as $$(1-x)\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\cosh\sqrt{x}$$

Then I expand to get $$(1-x)\left(1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac x {2!}+\frac {x^2} {4!}+\frac{x^3}{6!}+\cdots\right)$$

Now multiplying these brackets and simplifying takes a while (pretty long for my exam time), so is there a faster method to do this or to multiply these brackets?

Comment: It helps to start with $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\frac{2}{1+x}-1=1-2x+2x^2-\cdots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unnecessary to break up $1-x$ and $\frac{1}{1+x}$ into two separate series.  You can just differentiate $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ directly.  As J.G. pointed out in his comment, it may be easier to rewrite the expression as $\frac{2}{1+x} - 1$ or $2(x + 1)^{-1} - 1$.  This gives you $\frac{1-x}{1+x} = 1 - 2x + 2x^2 - 2x^3 + 2x^4 - 2x^5 + 2x^6 - 2x^7 + ...$.

Then you just have *two* series to multiply together.

Comment: @YoussefMohamed: Just algebra.  Perhaps it's easier to see if you make a substitution $u = 1+x$, so $\frac{1-x}{1+x} = \frac{1-(u-1)}{u} = \frac{2-u}{u} = \frac{2}{u} - 1 = \frac{2}{1 + x} - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly faster way might be to first compute the first 4 nonzero terms of
$$\frac{1}{1+x}\cosh\sqrt{x}$$
and then multiply the result by $x$ to get the first 4 nonzero terms of
$$\frac{x}{1+x}\cosh\sqrt{x}$$
and then subtract.

Answer (score 1):

The general expression is

$$
\left(\sum_{n} a_{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n} b_{n}\right)\left(\sum_{n} c_{n}\right)=\sum_{j} d_{j}
$$
where
$$
d_{k}=\sum_{i+j+l=k} a_{i} b_{j} c_{l}
$$

Maybe it will help you.